# PHP Array Object show unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW error

Tags: php

I have a problem, which seems to be in line `$this->pd_db = object(`
The shown error is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /var/www/website/includes/PD.php on line 10 `
```

Here is my code

```
$this->pd_db = object(
  'cstm'  => object(
    'table_name'      => "customdata",
    'table_version'   => '1.0'
  )
);
```

Please solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that it should look like :

```
$this->pd_db = (object)array(
  'cstm'  => (object)array(
    'table_name'      => "customdata",
    'table_version'   => '1.0'
  )
);
```

Though this seems like a pretty horrible idea...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to create an associative array, in which case you want:

```
$arr = array(
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => 'val2',
);
```

If you are actually wanting to use an object, object instantiation cannot be done with that syntax.  You would have to create an object and assigned properties:

```
$obj = new stdObject;
$obj->key1 = 'val1';
```

Edit: Did not know that you can cast an array to an object.  If that is your goal, tereško's way is better.

Comment: Well, the error message is because it's invalid syntax.  Basically it's saying unexpected double arrow token because it makes no sense there.